# schedule a python code execution from a static ip (azure architecture)

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-functions, static-ip-address, azure-runbook

- I have a python code that uses a virtual machine with reserved static ip, to receive data from a web service every minute.
- Since we are working with azure architecture, I built the virtual machine with this ip, and I installed python to schedule and execute the code. After a month, I realized that this method is not so consistent, cause I cant monitor the errors that appears, sometime the machine restarts,,, etc.
- Is there another way to do similar solution, keeping in mind that I can use only this static ip to receive the data from the web service.
- I tried to check the azure function or azure run book, but there are no way to run them from the cloud under the reserved ip.

Comment: AKS support static ip, failovers and easy to monitor IO and etc. You can create simple Deployment, Service and to monitor problems

Answer (score 0):

Curious on why it needs to be a static IP that you send data to and not a host name (e.g. myfunction.azurewebsites.net).  You are right here, but seems like a tough requirement.  Other option would be spinning up something like Azure API Management in front of the Azure Function.  API Management will give you a static IP and can then proxy the request to the function - but will be a cost to adding API Management.

Other option is likely AKS as Ami mentioned, which should do a little nicer at orchestrating and making sure the container is available while giving a static IP, but may be a bit overkill depending on what the code is doing.